# SNAPSHOT_SERIALIZATION_ERROR Duplicated property JaVers

Tags: exception, serialization, snapshot, javers

When i create an object, it commits it correctly, however, when i edit it, i obtain the following exception:

12:32:20.244 [http-nio-8082-exec-9] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is JaversException SNAPSHOT_SERIALIZATION_ERROR: error while serializing snapshot of 'com.tesicnor.tcheck.equipment.data.model.Equipment/92849', duplicated property 'Field ValueType:String equipmentStatus, declared in Detectable'] with root cause
org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: SNAPSHOT_SERIALIZATION_ERROR: error while serializing snapshot of 'com.tesicnor.tcheck.equipment.data.model.Equipment/92849', duplicated property 'Field ValueType:String equipmentStatus, declared in Detectable'

My entity Equipment contains an equipmentStatus, and this entity extends from another one, named Detectable, which also contains a equipmentStatus field. However there are more fields where the same occurs. Any idea of how solving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put two fields with the same name into one class - you are asking for trouble. It's the antipattern. Javers serializes object snapshots as a Map: propertyName -> propertyValue. Obviously, if you have duplicted fields a Snapshot can't be serialized properly. Try to remove duplicated field.

Comment: I've figured it out! Thank you!